# MySQL multi statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, temp-tables

What happens is that I'm working with google maps api and I have a database with some shops, the database is the direction of these, that with a javascript get the distance between the store and the location of user, the topic I want to sort by proximity, what I did was a first page which calculates all away and then redirects the following format `"pagina.php?data=(ID, DISTANCE),(ID, DISTANCE), ..... "`

then get the parameter

```
<?php $data = $ _GET['data'] ?>   // and example of "data" -> "(1,1582),(2,3568)," end with comma
```

And I'm trying to use this command "" THAT WORKS IN phpMYAdmin ""

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE distancias_temporales (id int(50) NOT NULL, distancia DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00);

INSERT INTO distancias_temporales (id, distancia) VALUES (1, 14.25), (2, 13.34);

SELECT * FROM talleres,distancias_temporales WHERE distancias_temporales.id = talleres.ID ORDER BY distancia ASC;
```

Of course to do dynamic change values​​:

```
$ data = "(-1, -1)";
if (isset ($ _GET ['data'])) {
    $ data = $ _GET ['data']. "(-1, -1)";
}
```

and in the second line:

```
 "INSERT INTO d (id, distancia) VALUES ".$data.";";
```

but mysql send my an error
according to what he tells me the page, the code is sent as I want

But it does not work when I try to put on the page ...

anyone can help me, the problem I think would be the multi query

Comment: What mysql extension are you using to submit the queries? mysql and PDO don't support multi-queries, only mysqli does.

Comment: Please post the error message sent by mysql. Also, what is the value of $data after the assignment of $_GET['data']."(-1,-1)" ?

Comment: P.S. Don't put a space after `$` in your PHP. It's allowed, but no one writes that way so it's hard to read. The `$` is part of the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL can handle multiple insert statements. Barmar makes a good point that some connection managers do not handle that construct.

Assuming the SQL is sent unaltered, it appears a comma is missing in the assignment of $data.

```
$ data = $ _GET ['data']. "(-1, -1)";
```

should be...

```
$data = $ _GET['data'] . ", (-1, -1)";
```

If and only if the value $_GET['data'] is not empty, e.g. data="(ID, DISTANCE),(ID, DISTANCE)".

Comment: I miss that, this is OK, beaucse de end of data is " , "